# SqlServer large nvarchar clustered index

Tags: sql-server, azure, database-design, database-schema, clustered-index

I have a table for caching geocoding results where I had planned to use the search string as the primary key/clustered index, since I wanted this to be both unique and indexed for quick lookup.  This would be pretty big, probably nvarchar(300). I've seen that large cluster keys are generally advised against due to size and performance, and I suppose that uniqueness isn't critical since i'm just caching results, so is there a better way to achieve this?

The search string can contain optional bounding coordinates that could be put into a separate column, but they do form part of the uniqueness identity.

Also i'd want to keep this table compatible with Sql Azure, which requires a clustered index somewhere in the table.

Comment: The basis for a good clustering key is that it is [unique, narrow, static and ever-increasing](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/more-considerations-for-the-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-continues/). This certainly fails on being narrow, and while I don't know your data, I expect that it fails on being ever increasing. This makes it a poor candidate for the clustering key. I'd be inclined to use a surrogate primary key as the clustering key, and create a new unique (if necessary) nonclustered index on the longer column for faster lookups.

Comment: You could also include commonly used columns as [non key columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190806.aspx) in this index to reduce the number of queries that require a key lookup.

Comment: Instead of stuffing the cache key into a string, can you store it in separate columns with the appropriate data types? A PK can span multiple columns.

Comment: @GarethD Given I didn't have use for the surrogate key myself (its a single isolated table) I guess my decision was based on whether it was better to have an additional clustered key as well as the unique nonclustered index or just the natural clustering key. Having read some of the reasoning in your link I'm still not certain which is better in this specific situation, but I figured sqlserver might be doing something under the hood with clustering key that im not aware of so I went with your suggestion. If you add it as an answer i'll mark it correct.

Comment: There is literally nothing I could post in an answer that hasn't already been said by Kimberly Tripp in either the article I linked to, or the links at the top that article. Were I to post an answer it would either be a link only answer, or just copy and pasting from those answers. I don't condone answers of either nature. I think it is best to just leave the question unanswered with the hope of someone one day posting something that adds to the link above. There is no reason a question has to have an answer for the sake of it, and I haven't really answered the question.